# java: printing current backtrace

Tags: java, red5, backtrace

is there a way to add a command in Java to add the current backtrace ?

I'm writing a red5 application and the appDisconnect function is being called twice. whenever a user changes room. I want to add a function at the beginning of the appDisconnect function that shows the current backtrace and then I can see what called it.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can output the stack trace to the current line like this:

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

Or if you need programmattic acces the the stacktrace elements you can use

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Comment: Thread.dumpStack() is also an equivalent of "new Exception.printStackTrace()".

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of is to look at:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Although this sounds more like a `logging` issue than actually observing the call trace. You could also try to setup `debug` execution in your IDE and add a few well placed breakpoints.