# Java: Within abstract class create method that gets name of extending class

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

Thanks in advance for the help.

First off, I don't think what I want to do is possible, but I thought I might ask anyway.  I have an abstract class foo with a method bar.  I have several classes that extend this class and none override the method bar (though all frequently call bar).  I am trying to debug an issue and would like to print out the name of the class that calls bar.  So if a class temp extends foo and calls bar, "temp" will be printed out.

One approach would be to override the bar method for every class that extends foo, but this would be a bit of a pain since it also instantiates private variables in foo.  I would therefore need separate methods to instantiate each variable that is private in foo to override bar in temp.

What I would like to do is something like this

```
System.out.println(Class.getSimpleName());
```

but I can't do this because getSimpleName() is not a static method and therefore can be called within something that can't be instantiated.  Another approach would be to make foo a normal class (ie not abstract).  However, I would really prefer not to do this.

Is there anyway that I can do what I would like to do or am I going to have to "bite the proverbial bullet"?

Edit:
This code is part of an android application.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077770/java-printing-current-backtrace) help? You would basically stick that in your `foo` method within the abstract class.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `this.getClass().getSimpleName()`. This will only print the class name of the object (of a subclass), not Foo itself.

Comment: No it won't.  I should have specified that I am using this java class in an android application.  I have editing my question to reflect this

Comment: @Codebender worked like a charm.  If you want to add an answer I will accept it.  Why might this have worked over Class.getSimpleName()?

Comment: Because `getSimpleName` is not a static method. You need a *specific `Class` instance* for it to work.

Comment: @user2736423 it works because this.getClass() returns the class object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do something like,

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

This will only print the class name of the object (of a subclass), not Foo itself.

It work's because `this` refers to the object (which belongs to a concrete subclass) and NOT the class itself (Foo in this case) it's being used in.

Comment: I noticed that this, "getClass().getSimpleName()" worked as well.

Comment: Yes. You can always call methods or fields without the `this` keyword. But using it will make the code more readable.